# Docker Node: Entrypoint can't be found

Tags: javascript, node.js, docker, docker-compose

I have the following `Dockerfile_dev` docker file:

```
FROM node:alpine
MAINTAINER "Desyllas Dimitrios"

ENV NEO4J_HOST=""
ENV NEO4J_USER=""
ENV NEO4J_PASSWORD=""
ENV MONGO_CONNECTION_STRING=""
ENV LOGS_DIR="/var/log/data_map"

COPY ./docker_scripts/entrypoint_dev.sh /usr/local/bin/entrypoint.sh

RUN chmod +x /usr/local/bin/entrypoint.sh &&\
    chown root:root /usr/local/bin/entrypoint.sh &&\
    mkdir -p /opt/map &&\
    mkdir -p /var/log/data_map &&\
    chmod 0666 /var/log/data_map

EXPOSE 7474
VOLUME /var/log/data_map
VOLUME /opt/map

WORKDIR /opt/map

ENTRYPOINT ['/usr/local/bin/entrypoint.sh']
```

And I have the following entrypoint:

```
#!/bin/sh

cd /opt/map

npm install
npm start
```

And the build image is launched via the following docker-compose

```
version: '2'
services:

  data_map_dev:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile_dev
    image: 'pcmagas/data-map:dev'
    links:
      - 'neo4j_dev'
      - 'mongodb'
    volumes:
      - './src:/opt/map/src'
      - './www:/opt/map/www'
      - './package.json:/opt/map/package.json'
      - './docker-volumes/app_dev:/var/log/datamap'
    ports:
      - "9781:9780"
    environment:
      NEO4J_HOST: 'neo4j_dev'
      NEO4J_USER: 'neo4j'
      NEO4J_PASSWORD: 'neo4j'
      MONGO_CONNECTION_STRING: 'mongodb://mongodb:map_dev'

  neo4j_dev:
    image: 'neo4j'
    ports:
      - '7474:7474'
    volumes:
      - './docker-volumes/neo4j_dev/data:/data'
    environment:
      NEO4J_AUTH: 'neo4j/neo45j'

  mongodb:
    image: 'mongo'
    ports:
      - '27017:27017'
    volumes:
      - './docker-volumes/mongodb/:/data/db'
```

I build it with `docker-compose build --no-cache --force-rm` and when I launch it via `docker-compose up` it cannot locate the entrypoint script as you see on the message:

> data_map_dev_1   | /bin/sh: [/usr/local/bin/entrypoint.sh]: not found

Do you have any idea why? I have a similar problem on [my project](https://github.com/pc-magas/data-mapper) too.

Comment: @KARTHIKEYAN.A You've recently created many low-quality tags that I've had to revert. For example [json-syntax] is not a good tag. Please don't create new tags unless you're certain that you know what you're doing.

Comment: Sure, i understand. thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your JSON syntax is wrong.

> Note: The exec form is parsed as a JSON array, which means that you must use double-quotes (“) around words not single-quotes (‘).

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/

Switch to double quotes like this:

```
ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/local/bin/entrypoint.sh"]
```